# Print binary reprensentation of individual characters

Tags: python, string, split

I have a function that converts characters to binary

```
def binary(value):
    return ''.join(format(ord(i), 'b') for i in value)

print(binary('a'))  # 1100001  
print(binary('b'))  # 1100010
```

But when I give multiple characters, they are joined together

```
print(binary('ab')) # 11000011100010
```

I want to find a way to split these apart into the individual letters. E.g.

```
'11000011100010' -> '1100001 1100010'
```

Comment: How do you define the chunks?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Did you mean `' '.join(...)`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist That would put spaces between each character. I think they want byte octets

Comment: @Grismar. I think OP just want a space between each letter

Comment: @OneCricketeer. Fair enough. At that point "needs details or clarity" seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to store all the generated binaries in a list then join all the items.

```
def binary(a):
    output=[]
    for i in a:                       
        binary = format(ord(i), '08b')
        #print(binary)
        output.append(binary)
    print("output: ", ' '.join(output))

   
binary('ram')
```

you will get the output like below.

```
output:  01110010 01100001 01101101
```

Comment: `format(ord(i), '08b')` returns a string, not a list, so don't think it needs joined

Comment: @OneCricketeer Here I am storing the output of "format(ord(i), '08b')" in a list so any other required function such as sorting, can also be performed.

Comment: I think you misunderstood... `''.join(format(ord('a'), '08b')) == format(ord('a'), '08b')` is True

Answer (score 0):

Your binary sequences have a length that's the number of bits required to just represent the number (happens to be 7 in both cases here) - but they could be very different lengths. You are throwing that information away in your ''.join() call and there's no way to retrieve that. Why not return a list of strings, instead of concatenating them all?

I.e:

```
# when passed value='ab', this will compute the binary representation of 'a'
# and then 'b', both 7 bits, and combine them into a single string of bits,
# 14 characters long; however the fact that these strings were both 7 
# characters long gets lost (could have been 6+8, 8+6, etc.)
def binary(value):
    return ''.join(format(ord(i), 'b') for i in value)


print(binary('ab'))  # prints all 14 characters
```

So, if you instead:

```
def binary(value):
    return [format(ord(i), 'b') for i in value]


print(binary('ab'))
```

The result is:

```
['1100001', '1100010']
```

You can work with those like this:

```
bs = binary('ab')
print(bs[0])
print(bs[1])
print(''.join(bs))
```

Result:

```
1100001
1100010
11000011100010
```

If, for example, you just want a space between each block:

```
print(' '.join(bs))
```

Result:

```
1100001 1100010
```

Padding to 8-bit words:

```
print(' '.join(b.zfill(8) for b in bs))
```

Result:

```
01100001 01100010
```

However, be careful with something like `bs = binary('课题')`.

Comment: (sort of unrelated): How would I convert the variable bs into a byte,
e.g. 'a' -> '01100001'?

Comment: Well, you say "a bit" but you really mean an 8-character representation of an 8-bit word (which would be a byte) - you just want to pad the values with zeroes, so look at `zfill()`; however, keep in mind that values over 255 will be more bits and your string could contain characters outside ascii (unless you're sure it's ascii-only)

Answer (score 0):

You lose any spacing information with `''.join`. Instead, format each character, then join later.

```
def binary(value):
    for c in value:
         yield format(ord(c), 'b')


print(' '.join([x for x in binary('ab')]))
# '1100001 1100010'
```